# How to use a variable from one component in another component

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 component which are stored in diferent files. 1.GetUser() , 2. App(), 3. Form(). I want to use two variables from GetUser component, which are stored in `data.user.map(({ name, email })`. Here i speack about `name` and `email`. I want to use these variables in Form component in `if(myValue === "name"&&myValue2 ==="email"){`, instead "name" string and "email" string. How to use these variables outside their component?

```js
function GetUser () {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USER);

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;
    const test = { myVal:"demo"};
    return data.user.map(({ name, email }) => (
      <div >
        <p>
          {console.log(name)}
        </p>
      </div>
    ));
  }
  export default GetUser;
  
  
  function App() {
  return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <p>Form Validation</p>
            <Home text = {'danger'}/> 
            <Home text = {'no-dangerr'}/> 
            <Form />
            {/* <GetUser /> */}
          </header>
        </div>
     
  );
}

export default App;

const Form:FunctionComponent<myForm> = ({title, valueInput}) =>{

    

    function submitForm(e:any){
       
        if(myValue === "name"&&myValue2 ==="email"){
             setLabel("Valid")         
        }else{
            setLabel("Not Valid")         
        }
    }

    return(
        
        <div>
            <form className>
                <label>{labelVal}
                <input onChange = {event =>setTitle(event.target.value)} type = 'text' placeholder = 'type name'/>
                <input onChange = {event =>setTitle2(event.target.value)} type = 'email' placeholder = 'type email'/>
                </label>
                <button onClick = {submitForm}>SUBMIT</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    )
}
export default Form;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify some terminology: you want to use the *values* of some variables in another component. You cannot use the variables themselves because they are declared in a different scope. Now a question: you have an array named `data.user` with several objects that have `name` and `email`. Which one of these values do you want to use in the `Form` component? Or do you want to use the entire list?

Comment: Also what is `useQuery()`? Is this a function you wrote? Or is it from some library?

Comment: It will also help if you draw the different screens that a user should see in your app. When the user first loads your page, what will it look like? What elements can they click on? And for each of those, what happens? Use MS Paint or a similar program to draw each of these screens and describe how the user navigates between them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice , i want to use both variables. Here i didn't insert all code. I tought that maybe someone knows how to use for example `useContext` hook from reactjs or another idea. I want to know only a solution of exporting the variables and using them in another component.

Comment: You are correct. You can use React context to solve this problem. I suggest that you read a tutorial on how to do so.

Comment: The basic concept is that you store the user name and email in a global state and then you get them in any component that needs them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice , i tried but i didn't succed. I know that i should create context in that component from where i want to export may data and to wrap it with <provider>, and the second step is using useContext in that component where i want to import my data. But for some reasons it doesn't work for me. Could you please provide a small code using useContext?

Comment: Part of your difficulty here is that `GetUser` probably shouldn't be a component. It appears to be code that gets some data from...somewhere. I can only help if you show what `useQuery()` does. Also, if you need help with how to use `useContext`, then you should post a new question showing what you did and explain what troubles you encountered.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, `The basic concept is that you store the user name and email in a global state and then you get them in any component that needs them.`, how to do this? i mean hoe to define a variable from a function as a global variable?

Comment: "how to define a variable from a function as a global variable" This is the wrong way to look at it. Instead, you store the values in context and you share them from there to all components that need them. If you haven't read the official React documentation about how to do this, then you should. If you still have problems, post a new question showing what you have tried with `useContext`.

Comment: I haven't used React Context before, so I probably am not explaining it well in the above comments. From what I read now, you store the data in a provider and then access it using context. There are lots of tutorials online. I suggest you work through one of them to learn how it works.